# Accessing R studio from Linux server

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, rhel, rstudio-server

I have installed R and RStudio on a linux server and it is working fine. I can login to the server through putty and R works when I write 'R' in putty. However when I try to login to [server]:8787 through web interface, it gives me wrong username/password error.

I tried adding a new user to the server using 'useradd' as I am sudo user of the server and changed it password. This user was able to login to [server]:8787 for R-Studio.

I think I need to make changes to 'PAM' setting but I have never done that before. Any help with this that enables all the users who have access to the server can access RStudio so that I do not have to create accounts using useradd everytime will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to resolve this issue:

sudo cp /etc/pam.d/login /etc/pam.d/rstudio